# CentOS 9 Stream - errors doing yum update

Tags: centos, yum, centos8

I'm coming in from using Ubuntu.

Just installed CentOS on my DEV server and right away having issues just doing an update or installing new packages.

Here is the error:

```
sudo yum update

Last metadata expiration check: 0:41:22 ago on Tue 15 Feb 2022 10:38:21 AM.
Error:

 Problem 1: problem with installed package libidn2-2.3.0-7.el9.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libidn2-2.3.0-7.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libunistring.so.0()(64bit) needed by libidn2-2.3.2-1.el7.x86_64

 Problem 2: cannot install the best update candidate for package python3-tracer-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
  - problem with installed package python3-tracer-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
  - package python3-tracer-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch requires tracer-common = 0.7.5-4.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package tracer-common-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
  - cannot install both tracer-common-0.7.8-1.el7.noarch and tracer-common-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
```

Here are the enabled repos:

```
yum repolist enabled
repo id       repo name
appstream     CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream
baseos        CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS
epel          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64
extras-common CentOS Stream 9 - Extras packages
remi-safe     Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_6
```

I have tried to:

```
sudo yum update --best --allowerasing
```

But its still complaining:

```
Problem 1: problem with installed package libidn2-2.3.0-7.el9.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libidn2-2.3.0-7.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libunistring.so.0()(64bit) needed by libidn2-2.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
 Problem 2: cannot install the best update candidate for package python3-tracer-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
  - problem with installed package python3-tracer-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
  - package python3-tracer-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch requires tracer-common = 0.7.5-4.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package tracer-common-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
  - cannot install both tracer-common-0.7.8-1.el7.noarch and tracer-common-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

UPDATE:

Tried

```
yum clean all
yum check
yum check-update
yum update

yum update --nobest
```

Same result:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:49:35 ago on Tue 15 Feb 2022 11:30:57 AM.
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package libidn2-2.3.0-7.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libunistring.so.0()(64bit) needed by libidn2-2.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
 Problem 2: package python3-tracer-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch requires tracer-common = 0.7.5-4.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both tracer-common-0.7.8-1.el7.noarch and tracer-common-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package tracer-common-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package python3-tracer-0.7.5-4.el9.noarch
==================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                Architecture                    Version                               Repository                     Size
==================================================================================================================================================
Skipping packages with conflicts:
(add '--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade):
 tracer-common                          noarch                          0.7.8-1.el7                           epel                           31 k
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 libidn2                                x86_64                          2.3.2-1.el7                           epel                          148 k
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> baseos        CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS
> epel          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64
> extras-common CentOS Stream 9 - Extras packages

You are using old EPEL (and "remi") for EL-7 while you are running EL-9

You need to remove epel-release and remi-release and install the proper versions.

Comment: Is it fun seeing people use your repo in the wild? :D

Comment: Not fun, as quite common ;)  but always "strange" and "sad" to see people asking in random places instead of dedicated ones (forum, github issues, irc, discord...)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
yum clean all
yum check
yum check-update
yum update
```

If there is still a problem, try:

`yum update --nobest`

Comment: I have tried this and its still throwing the same error - added output to my original post.

Comment: It almost feels like there are two repos with same package that are conflicting with each other.

Comment: I think its coming from epel repo. When doing sudo yum --disablerepo=epel updates, the errors do not show up. The problem is that I cant install htop without it.

Comment: @KalvinKlien you're most likely correct. Epel and remi-safe might be conflicting.

Comment: Are you sure this is a clean install? You shouldn't be having these problems if that was the case. Just need to enable to epel repo and you're set.

Comment: Yes, just installed CentOS 9 Stream yesterday. Its has Desktop version with GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I copy pasted and added epel from CentOS 7 so it was conflicting with existing one on the CentOS 9.

Used this to remove the older repo:

```
sudo yum remove epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

FYI: there is apparently epel-next:

https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-enable-epel-epel-next-repository-on-centos-9-stream/

UPDATE:

As others mentioned there is an updated official guide to repos on CentOS9:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#_centos_stream_9

Comment: That guide is outdated and inaccurate.  You're better off following the official instructions.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#_centos_stream_9